# edX and installing Django

Tags: python

I'm not sure if I'm in the right place here. I have a macBook Pro and am starting to get used to it - I used Windows previously and have not really used Python and Django. So, new to mac, new to Python, new to Django.

I'm trying to download and install the edX courseware software and need to run a couple of command line instructions:
i.e.

Install the requirements and register the XBlock entry points with (you may
    need to sudo this if you don't use virtualenv):

```
    $ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

1. Run the Django development server:

   ```
   $ python manage.py runserver
   ```

At the end of the pip install I get the error:

> creating /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/man
>
> error: could not create '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/man': Permission denied

It looks to me like it's a permissions issue but I have full `permissions` on the folder where I've installed the download. Could it be the already installed version of `Python` that comes with the macBook? If so, how do I get around it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try: `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Indeed, I wrote, "you may need to sudo this if you don't use virtualenv" in the instructions....

Comment: Works - hey ho - something new, two steps forward, one step back Thanks, Thanks, Thanks